# How to serve robots.txt from Masonite

Tags: python-3.x, robots.txt, masonite

I want to serve the files like `robots.txt`, `humans.txt` and `manifest.json`.

I saw the docs, I didn't find a solution, I have found `view.render` only serve HTML not text or JSON or any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add folder path and alias in `config/storage.py`

```
# config/storage.py

STATICFILES = {
    'storage/static': 'static/',
    'storage/compiled': 'static/',
    'storage/uploads': 'static/',
    'storage/root': '/' # add this line
}
```

Create `root` folder inside `storage` and put the `robots.txt` in `root` folder.

visit [localhost:8000/robots.txt](http://localhost:8000/robots.txt)